# Gnu/Linux: export results of find command including file creation date

Tags: find

I use this command in order to save the name of all the zip files under a directory, to a file.

```
find . -iname \*.zip > zipfiles.txt
```

How can I also include the creation date of the files?

Now the contents of zipfiles.txt are:

```
/dir/file1.zip 
/dir2/file2.zip
```

I want to include the creation date so something like this:

```
/dir/file1.zip 1/1/2019 13:15:23
/dir2/file2.zip 1/2/2018 23:55:53
```

Comment: @GAD3R I dont want to append it to the filename, but next to each filename in the txt file. Please check updated post

Comment: By _creation time_, do you mean the inode birth time (when the file came into existence), or the _last modification time_ (when the content of the file was fully created)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I want the date that the file was created

Comment: that is not answering my question. What do you consider the time the file is created? When it appeared or when it was fully created?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I dont fully understand the difference between them... But I guess it doesn't matter much so I will need the Last modification time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 find . -iname '*.zip' -printf '%p %TY/%Tm/%Td %.8TT\n' > zipfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `find`, you can do:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -printf '%p %TFT%TT%Tz+\n'
```

which gives an output like:

```
./file.zip 2018-03-04T13:23:21.0321012380+0000
```

Comment: I want to export this information in the zipfiles.txt file, next to each zip file name